# Angular2 Custom Component in NgSwitch

Tags: angular

I'm trying to render 1 of 6 custom components based on the aType.Name's value inside a ngFor loop.  Here is my switch syntax:

```
 <div *ngFor="let aType of resourceTypes; let i = index" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" [ngClass]="{'active': i==0}" [attr.id]="aType.Name">
                <span [ngSwitch]="aType.Name">
                    {{aType.Name}} tab content here
                    <config-resource-editor [application]="application" [ngSwitchWhen]="Config"></config-resource-editor>
                    <mvc-resource-editor [application]="application" [ngSwitchWhen]="MVC"></mvc-resource-editor>
                    <other-resource-editor [application]="application"  [ngSwitchWhen]="Other"></other-resource-editor>
                    <wcf-resource-editor [application]="application"  [ngSwitchWhen]="WCF"></wcf-resource-editor>
                    <web-resource-editor [application]="application"  [ngSwitchWhen]="Web"></web-resource-editor>
                    <webapi-resource-editor [application]="application"  [ngSwitchWhen]="WebAPI"></webapi-resource-editor>
                </span>
   </div>
```

When its producing this error:`ncaught EXCEPTION: Error in ../PosItAdmin/Authorization/Resource/Ng2ApplicationResourceList:24:24
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for TemplateRef!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:3776:27)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4307:20)
    at new NoProviderError (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4342:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5794:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5822:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5785:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5594:25)
    at ElementInjector.get (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:9809:52)
    at ElementInjector.get (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:9809:52)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (https://localhost/POSITAdmin/Scripts/npmlibs/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5819:28)`
I can find examples on ngSwitch but none of them are trying to render a custom component in the switchWhen block.  What is the proper way of doing this?

Thanks!

After removing the [] and adding template to the component elements i get no js errors, but the custom components aren't linking to my elements.  For example this is my new ngFor with embedded ngSwitch:

```
 <div *ngFor="let aType of resourceTypes; let i = index" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" [ngClass]="{'active': i==0}" [attr.id]="aType.Name">
                <span ngSwitch="aType.Name">
                    {{aType.Name}} tab content here
                    <config-resource-editor [application]="application" ngSwitchWhen="Config" template></config-resource-editor>
                    <mvc-resource-editor [application]="application" ngSwitchWhen="MVC" template></mvc-resource-editor>
                    <other-resource-editor [application]="application" ngSwitchWhen="Other" template></other-resource-editor>
                    <wcf-resource-editor [application]="application" ngSwitchWhen="WCF" template></wcf-resource-editor>
                    <web-resource-editor [application]="application" ngSwitchWhen="Web" template></web-resource-editor>
                    <webapi-resource-editor [application]="application" ngSwitchWhen="WebAPI" template></webapi-resource-editor>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Here is what an example component looks like :

```
    import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {IApplication, IApplicationFilterData, IResourceType} from './application';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouteParams } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { ApplicationService} from './application.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'config-resource-editor',
    template: '<div>Other editor thingy.  {{application.Name}}</div>',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ConfigResourceEditorComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() application: IApplication;

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

}
```

but the component template doesn't render.

I didn't get the switch syntax figured out but ngIf's worked.  This is doing what I wanted:

```
<div *ngFor="let aType of resourceTypes; let i = index" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" [ngClass]="{'active': i==0}" [attr.id]="aType.Name">
                <config-resource-editor [application]="application" *ngIf="aType.Name == 'Config'" ></config-resource-editor>
                <mvc-resource-editor [application]="application"  *ngIf="aType.Name == 'MVC'" ></mvc-resource-editor>
                <other-resource-editor [application]="application" *ngIf="aType.Name == 'Other'"></other-resource-editor>
                <wcf-resource-editor [application]="application" *ngIf="aType.Name == 'WCF'"></wcf-resource-editor>
                <web-resource-editor [application]="application" *ngIf="aType.Name == 'Web'"></web-resource-editor>
                <webapi-resource-editor [application]="application" *ngIf="aType.Name == 'WebAPI'"></webapi-resource-editor>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are `Config`, `MVN`, `Other`, ... strings or properties on your component? In case they are strings, remove `[]` around `ngSwitchWhen`

Comment: They are strings.  I have removed them.  I'll update my question with the new behavior.

Comment: If you use `ngSwitch` on non-template tags you need to add `*` `*ngSwitch="Config"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- remove `[]` around `ngSwitch` to get the values treated as trings
- add `*` to get `*ngSwitch` which is required for structural directives if they are not added to a `<template>` tag

See also [NgSwitch directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html)